# Javascript Mouseevent On Hover

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am looking for some help with my mouse over event.

```
<div class="video-container">
<video id="my_video" loop muted poster="IMAGE_URL"> <!-- put your image here -->
  <source src="VIDEO_URL" type="video/mp4"> <!-- path to your video here -->
</video>
</div>
```

Above is my `video-container`, on my index page I am displaying 10 videos. Each of them should show a preview of the video when being hovered, however with my current javascript only the first video with `my_video` id is displaying the video preview when hovering.

```
let myVideo = document.getElementById("my_video");
myVideo.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    myVideo.play()
    image.style.display = 'none'
});

myVideo.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    myVideo.pause();
});
```

How can I make it so that all videos on my homepage, behave in the same manner?

Comment: Do all the `video` tags have the same ID? If so, that is part of your problem as IDs **MUST** be unique. `document.getElementById` will return one element and one element only.

Comment: @JonP yea, they are all the same ID.. can you maybe help me understand how I can make them unique, and still be able to find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do the `getElementById`, it only covers one element. And ID **must be unique to elements in HTML**, you cannot have multiple elements with same ID. You can give all of the `video` elements the same class and apply all of them at once, or just apply to all `video` elements directly

```js
let myVideos = document.querySelectorAll("video");
myVideos.forEach(vid => {
  vid.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    vid.play();
  });
  vid.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    vid.pause();
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <video id="my_video_1" loop muted poster="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tiverton.ri.gov%2Fimg%2Fcontent%2Ftrees%2Fhome_tree.png&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=c0fbdc7aa01163cdffb57908bb424286af2ebd3b6352a581d61660f31a299a51&ipo=images"> <!-- put your image here -->
  <source src="VIDEO_URL" type="video/mp4"> <!-- path to your video here -->
</video>
<video id="my_video_2" loop muted poster="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tiverton.ri.gov%2Fimg%2Fcontent%2Ftrees%2Fhome_tree.png&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=c0fbdc7aa01163cdffb57908bb424286af2ebd3b6352a581d61660f31a299a51&ipo=images"> <!-- put your image here -->
  <source src="VIDEO_URL" type="video/mp4"> <!-- path to your video here -->
</video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple elements with the same ID. This is your problem, ID's must be unique.

You want something like this

Note you also should [not use fat arrow functions for event listeners](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/when-you-should-not-use-arrow-functions/#:%7E:text=An%20arrow%20function%20doesn%27t,that%20uses%20the%20arguments%20object.)

```js
//Get the video elements we want
let videos = document.querySelectorAll(".video-container video");

//Loop the elements
videos.forEach((el) => {
  //Add the event listeners
  el.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    console.log("Play " + this.querySelector("source").src);
    this.play();
  });

  el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    console.log("Pause " + this.querySelector("source").src);
    this.pause();
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video loop muted poster="IMAGE_URL"> <!-- put your image here -->
  <source src="VIDEO_URL" type="video/mp4"> <!-- path to your video here -->
</video>
</div>
<div class="video-container">
  <video loop muted poster="IMAGE_URL"> <!-- put your image here -->
  <source src="VIDEO_URL2" type="video/mp4"> <!-- path to your video here -->
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: As I read in your reference, it should not be a problem to use fat arrow function as long as the program does not use `this` keyword, isn't it? However, it's interesting to know that and I am kind of curious whether it has side-effect on performance or not, could you tell me?

Comment: It's more that the `this` keyword has long been used in event listeners and is very powerful.  You will probably be ok with no performance side effects. It seems to be that the current best practice is **not** to use fat arrow. But best practices do change.